# Specify the shift for numpy.correlate

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I wonder if there is a possibility to specify the shift expressed by `k` variable for the cross-correlation of two 1D arrays. Because with the `numpy.correlate` function and its `mode` parameter set to `'full`' I will get cross-correlate coefficients for each `k` shift for whole length of the taken array (assuming that both arrays are the same size). Let me show you what I mean exactly on below example:

```
import numpy as np

# Define signal 1.
signal_1 = np.array([1, 2 ,3])

# Define signal 2.
signal_2 = np.array([1, 2, 3])

# Other definitions.
Xi = signal_1
Yi = signal_2
N = np.size(Xi)
k = 3
Xs = np.average(Xi)
Ys = np.average(Yi)

# Cross-covariance coefficient function.
def crossCovariance(Xi, Yi, N, k, Xs, Ys, forCorrelation = False):
    autoCov = 0
    for i in np.arange(0, N-k):
        autoCov += ((Xi[i+k])-Xs)*(Yi[i]-Ys)
    if forCorrelation == True:
        return autoCov/N
    else:
        return (1/(N-1))*autoCov

# Expected value function.
def E(X, P):
    expectedValue = 0
    for i in np.arange(0, np.size(X)):
        expectedValue += X[i] * (P[i] / np.size(X))
    return expectedValue 

# Cross-correlation coefficient function.
def crossCorrelation(Xi, Yi, k):
    # Calculate the covariance coefficient.
    cov = crossCovariance(Xi, Yi, N, k, Xs, Ys, forCorrelation = True)

    # Calculate standard deviations.
    EX = E(Xi, np.ones(np.size(Xi))) 
    SDX = (E((Xi - EX) ** 2, np.ones(np.size(Xi)))) ** (1/2)

    EY = E(Yi, np.ones(np.size(Yi)))
    SDY = (E((Yi - EY) ** 2, np.ones(np.size(Yi)))) ** (1/2)

    # Calculate correlation coefficient.
    return cov / (SDX * SDY)

# Express cross-covariance or cross-correlation function in a form of a 1D vector.
def array(k, norm = True):
    # If norm = True, return array of autocorrelation coefficients.
    # If norm = False, return array of autocovariance coefficients.
    vector = np.array([])
    shifts = np.abs(np.arange(-k, k+1, 1))
    for i in shifts:
        if norm == True:
            vector = np.append(crossCorrelation(Xi, Yi, i), vector)
        else:
            vector = np.append(crossCovariance(Xi, Yi, N, i, Xs, Ys), vector)
    return vector
```

In my example, calling the method `array(k, norm = True)` for different values of `k` will give resuslt as I shown below:

```
k = 3, [ 0.  -0.5  0.   1.   0.  -0.5  0. ]
k = 2, [-0.5  0.   1.   0.  -0.5]
k = 1, [ 0.  1.  0.]
k = 0, [ 1.]
```

My approach is good for the learning purposes but I need to move to the native numpy functions in order to speed up my analysis. How one could specify the `k` shift value while using the native `numpy.correlate` function? PS `k` parameter specify the "time" shift between two arrays. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in just a single `k`, or a range of `k`?

Comment: Single `k`, e.g `3`, but with the possibility to express the cross-correlation function in a form of a vector, like in the case of `mode='full'` - that is, calculating the cross-correlation coefficients for `<|-k|;k>`, i.e `k=[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]` for `k=3`.

Comment: Your example code does not give me the same results that you give below: `array(3, norm=True)` gives me `np.array([ 0., -0.33,  0.,  0.67,  0., -0.33,  0.])`. BTW `array` is not a good choice of name for your function, since it's not very informative and is easily confused with `np.array`.

Comment: 1. Why down-vote? 2. I don't know what are you doing, but above code snippet for `print(array(3, norm=True))` gives me `[ 0.  -0.5  0.   1.   0.  -0.5  0. ]`...

Comment: I've tried using two different machines and multiple different versions of numpy and I still can't reproduce your result. Using a new IPython session, can you try `%paste`ing your whole example into the interpreter and see what you get. If you're still getting the same result then all I can think is that there must be something wrong with your Python environment.

Comment: I've pasted the code above and the result is the same as in my last comment. Look: http://pastebin.com/x6KE4Q7d.

Comment: 1) I didn't downvote you. 2) I think I understand where the discrepancy is coming from - you must be using Python 3x, where [the division operator behaves differently compared with Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), which most numpy users are running.

Comment: Yep, I'm ussing Python 3.4.2, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I'm not aware of any built-in function for computing the cross-correlation for a particular range of signal lags, you can speed your version up a lot by vectorization, i.e. performing operations on arrays rather than single elements in an array.

This version uses only a single Python loop over the lags:

```
import numpy as np


def xcorr(x, y, k, normalize=True):

    n = x.shape[0]

    # initialize the output array
    out = np.empty((2 * k) + 1, dtype=np.double)
    lags = np.arange(-k, k + 1)

    # pre-compute E(x), E(y)
    mu_x = x.mean()
    mu_y = y.mean()

    # loop over lags
    for ii, lag in enumerate(lags):

        # use slice indexing to get 'shifted' views of the two input signals
        if lag < 0:
            xi = x[:lag]
            yi = y[-lag:]
        elif lag > 0:
            xi = x[:-lag]
            yi = y[lag:]
        else:
            xi = x
            yi = y

        # x - mu_x; y - mu_y
        xdiff = xi - mu_x
        ydiff = yi - mu_y

        # E[(x - mu_x) * (y - mu_y)]
        out[ii] = xdiff.dot(ydiff) / n

        # NB: xdiff.dot(ydiff) == (xdiff * ydiff).sum()

    if normalize:
        # E[(x - mu_x) * (y - mu_y)] / (sigma_x * sigma_y)
        out /=  np.std(x) * np.std(y)

    return lags, out
```

Some more general points of advice:

- As I mentioned in the comments, you should try to give your functions names that are informative, and that aren't likely to conflict with other things in your namespace (e.g. `array` vs `np.array`).
- It's much better to make your functions self-contained. In your version,  `N`, `k`, `Xs` and `Ys` are defined outside the main function. In this situation you might accidentally modify or overwrite one of these variables, and it can get tricky to debug errors caused by this sort of thing.
- Appending to numpy arrays (e.g. using `np.append` or `np.concatenate`) is slow, so avoid it whenever you can. If, as in this case, you know the size of the output ahead of time, it's much faster to pre-allocate the output array (e.g. using `np.empty` or `np.zeros`), then fill in the elements. If you absolutely have to do concatenation, it's often faster to  append to a normal Python `list`, then convert it to a numpy array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's available by specifying `maxlags`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xcorr = plt.xcorr(signal_1, signal_2, maxlags=1)
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xcorr). This implementation is based on np.correlate.